# Capturing client screen using vanilla java script for IE 5 or above?

Tags: javascript

I am aware of using canvas to capture client screen however some methods are not supported for IE 5 and 6. I am looking for recommended method to achieve this which will support all legacy browsers also.

Comment: and what have you tried so far? And why supporting a browser of the last century?

Comment: Those browsers don't exist anymore and have not for years....